# Combining ng-repeat and ng-bind-html?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-bind-html

I've got a list of messages of which the text includes some html which I want to display. So as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25891344/1650012) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22445290/angularjs-ng-bind-html-ng-repeat) what I'm currently trying is this:

```
<div ng-repeat="message in messages">
    {{ message.sender_name }} - <div ng-bind-html="message.text"></div>
</div>
```

It displays the `message.sender_name`, but not the `message.text`. When I simply do `{{ message.text }}` it displays the text correctly (but displaying the raw `<br>`s without rendering them).

Does anybody know why this is not working?

Comment: Have you included [ngSanitize](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngSanitize) in your module? You need ngSanitize for ng-bind-html to work.

Comment: Include/download http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.X.Y/angular-sanitize.js and list ngSanitize as dependency in your module declaration. Ex:- `angular.module('myapp', ['ngSanitize', ..deps])`

Comment: @PSL - Awesome! that was it! If you add your comment as an answer I can accept it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[ngBindHtml](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml) directive needs [$sce service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce) to parse and display the bound html. So you would need to include ngSanitize module in your module decalaration as a dependency for `ng-bind-html` to work.

You can download appropriate version of it from :-
http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.X.Y/angular-sanitize.js

Ex:-

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ngSanitize', ..otherdeps]);
```

Answer (score 1):

ng-bind-html Evaluates the expression and inserts the resulting HTML into the element in a secure way. By default, the resulting HTML content will be sanitized using the $sanitize service. To utilize this functionality, ensure that $sanitize is available, for example, by including ngSanitize in your module's dependencies (not in core Angular). In order to use ngSanitize in your module's dependencies, you need to include "angular-sanitize.js" in your application.
By the way this is the description from angular js documentation. You can also see examples of using angular-sanitize with ng-bind-html there.

Good luck.